# How to create model instances from html form and save to AuraDb?

Tags: python, django, neo4j, neomodel, neo4j-aura

Most of the online tutorials and videos describe how to create and save model instances to the local database using Django. I found this medium article https://medium.com/swlh/create-rest-api-with-django-and-neo4j-database-using-django-nemodel-1290da717df9 explaining how to upload it to Neo4j. I tried to run the same project and this is what I got when I went to http://127.0.0.1:8000/person (see snapshot below).

[image]

The "Person" object is a StructuredNode, defined as follows in `models/person.py`:

```
from neomodel import StructuredNode, StringProperty, IntegerProperty,UniqueIdProperty, RelationshipTo
from myapi.models.city import City


class Person(StructuredNode):
    uid = UniqueIdProperty()
    name = StringProperty(unique_index=False)
    age = IntegerProperty(index=True, default=0)
    email = StringProperty(unique_index=True)

    # Relations :
    city = RelationshipTo(City, 'LIVES_IN')
    friends = RelationshipTo('Person','FRIEND')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.uid
```

I want to get the details from a user through a form and save it as an instance of the Person object in my AuraDB: `person.save()` So in  `views/forms.py' I created a form as such:

```
from django import forms
from splitjson.widgets import SplitJSONWidget
from myapi.models import Person


class testForm(forms.Form):
    attrs = {'class': 'special', 'size': '40'}
    data = forms.CharField(widget=SplitJSONWidget(attrs=attrs, debug=True))
    class Meta:
        model = Person
```

and I added it as a path to the `urls.py`:

```
from django.urls import re_path as url
from myapi.views import *
from django.urls import path
urlpatterns = [
    path('', home, name='home'),
    path('home', home, name='home'),
    path('sign-up', sign_up, name='sign_up'),
    path('test-dict', test_dict, name='test_dict'),
    path('person',personDetails),
    path('getAllPersons',getAllPersons),
    path('city',cityDetails),
    path('getAllCities',getAllCities),
    path('connectPaC',connectPaC),
    path('connectPaP',connectPaP)
]
```

The path with the name `test-dict` leads to this function defined in `home.py`, which tries to access the `testForm` created earlier.:

```
from django.template import RequestContext
from .forms import testForm
from django.template.loader import render_to_string

def test_dict(request):
    json = {'name': 1,
            'age': 4}
    form = testForm(request.POST or None, initial={'data': json})
    if form.is_valid():
        # validate and save
        pass

    template = 'myapi/test_template.html'
    #context = RequestContext(request, render_to_string(form))
    return render(request, template, {'form': form})
```

And finally, this is how the `views/persons.py` looks like:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
from myapi.models import Person
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
import json
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect


def getAllPersons(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        try:
            persons = Person.nodes.all()
            response = []
            for person in persons :
                obj = {
                    "uid": person.uid,
                    "name": person.name,
                    "age": person.age,
                }
                response.append(obj)
            return JsonResponse(response, safe=False)
        except:
            response = {"error": "Error occurred"}
            return JsonResponse(response, safe=False)
@csrf_exempt
def personDetails(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        # get one person by name
        name = request.GET.get('name', ' ')
        try:
            person = Person.nodes.get(name=name)
            response = {
                "uid": person.uid,
                "name": person.name,
                "age": person.age,
            }
            return JsonResponse(response, safe=False)
        except :
            response = {"error":"Error occurred"}
            return JsonResponse(response, safe=False)
            #return render(response, 'myapi/test_template.html')

    if request.method == 'POST':
        # create one person
        json_data = json.loads(request.body)
        name = json_data['first_name']
        email = str(json_data['email'])
        try:
            person = Person(name=name, email=email)
            person.save()
            response = {
                "uid": person.uid,
            }
            return JsonResponse(response)
        except :
            response = {"error":"Error occurred"}
            return JsonResponse(response, safe=False)

    if request.method == 'PUT':
        # update one person
        json_data = json.loads(request.body)
        name = json_data['name']
        age = int(json_data['age'])
        uid = json_data['uid']
        try:
            person = Person.nodes.get(uid=uid)
            person.name = name
            person.age = age
            person.save()
            response = {
                "uid": person.uid,
                "name": person.name,
                "age": person.age,
            }
            return JsonResponse(response, safe=False)
        except:
            response = {"error":"Error occurred"}
            return JsonResponse(response, safe=False)

    if request.method == 'DELETE':
        # delete one person
        json_data = json.loads(request.body)
        uid = json_data['uid']
        try:
            person = Person.nodes.get(uid=uid)
            person.delete()
            response = {"success": "Person deleted"}
            return JsonResponse(response, safe=False)
        except:
            response = {"error":"Error occurred"}
            return JsonResponse(response, safe=False)
```

But it is still not working. I want to know how is it possible to create an instance of a 'Person' based on the input from a user through a form, and save it to AuraDB (the connection to AuraDB is working fine, by the way).
I guess it is surely possible, but since I am absolutely new, I might not be implementing it in the right way.

Comment: `class testForm(forms.ModelForm):`

Comment: @willeM_VanOnsem I tried your suggestion. It gave an error: `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Creating a ModelForm without either the 'fields' attribute or the 'exclude' attribute is prohibited; form testForm needs updating.`